# mysql - I dont understand what this means, can anyone explain each line of the script to me?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students (
Student_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
First_name VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
Middle_name VARCHAR (20),
Last_middle VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
Email VARCHAR (60) NOT NULL,
Password CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
Reg_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (student_id),
UNIQUE (email));
```

Comment: which part do you not understand?

Comment: all of it, I am a new coder

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html

Comment: I understand the first line (I think), does it mean that if a table already exists do not create another??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because .

Comment: why, how is this off topic??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It creates a new table "students" in the database if it doesn't exist already.

- Each row from " student_id" to "Reg_date" represent one column in the table.
- NOT NULL next to a column means you can't leave it empty when you insert data.
- "student_id" is a primary key, and is automatically incremented for each entry
- email has to be unique for every entry.
- VARCAR is a text entry, int is a number, DATETIME is a date.

I recommend you take some SQL tutorial. There are tons on the internet. This one is great: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Comment: thanks so much, will try it!

Answer (score 0):

This statement is saying that if the table in the database called `students`, does not exists, then create it.

Everything in the () after that is assuming that the table does not exist and is assigning the values to each column In the table.

INT means it's a number, VARCHAR means it's a string or anything in quotes ("") .

Not Null means that the value when put into the table cannot be null and will default to an empty string, I believe.

Primary key is the unique identifier of the dataset ( all the columns ). This is how you are able to quickly grab a row of data. You will notice that this(student_id)  auto increments above, to keep it unique.

The unique email is saying that this email must be unique in the database and cannot have duplicates.

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes it does, thank you very much